# Add logo to a c# asp.net mvc application?

Tags: html, css

My home page for this website is supposed to have the name listed as "My Golf App", the logo displayed beneath it (a jpeg image), and then buttons to enter, view, or search all of the information on the site. Instead of displaying the image that I have pointed to, all that displays for the image is the word "Logo" where the image should be displaying. My code is listed below.

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}

<div class="jumbotron">
    <h1>My Golf App</h1>
</div>

<p class="lead"><img id="img_logo" alt="Logo" src="@Url.Content("~/golf.jpeg")" /></p>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <p><a class="btn btn-default" href="/Home/Enter">Enter Course &raquo;</a></p>
        <p><a class="btn btn-default" href="/Home/List">List Courses &raquo;</a></p>
        <p><a class="btn btn-default" href="/Home/Search">Search for Course &raquo;</a></p>
        </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Does `golf.jpeg` exist in the location you are specifying?

Comment: Yeah, it's in the same folder as the page

Answer (score 0):

Your logo is not being found and so the browser is displaying the alt text like it should. Load the page in a browser, right click the "Logo" text, click "Inspect Element" then find the `img` tag. The path is most likely incorrect.